# How is Visual Studio using image file types for icons?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating a System Tray Application and I am trying to add my own icon file to the project. I have figured out a way to add the Icon by doing Add New Item -> Icon and then copying and pasting an image over from paint. Then of course I use the Icon with "new Icon("myicon.ico"). The file that is created has several Image File Types. My question is

How does Visual Studio use the image file types / sizes for Icons?

Meaning is 16x16 the default icon to be used for system tray? Should I have more than one Icon File if I am going to have different Icons for Application, Desktop and System Tray or Should I define multiple Image File Types in the .ico file? and if so, what sizes are for what?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to create icon for Windows Desktop app including WPF and Windows Forms (not for Windows Store app), this link will provide basic guide of icon size, how many colors, etc:

- Icon explained, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx
- Creating icon for Windows XP, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997636.aspx

For Windows Store application, there's no such thing as ICON. It's simply PNG or JPG file, combined with tiles.